# Interface variant return type

Tags: c#, interface

I have two classes for example. Each of them have a `Deconstruct()` method. How can I represent this in an interface?

```cs
public class A
{
    public Foo Foo { get; }
    public Bar Bar { get; }
    public Baz Baz { get; }

    public (Foo, Bar, Baz) Deconstruct()
    {
        return (Foo, Bar, Baz); 
    }
}

public class B 
{
    public Foo Foo { get; }
    public Bar Bar { get; }

    public (Foo, Bar) Deconstruct()
    {
        return (Foo, Bar);
    }
}

public interface IDeconstructable
{
    (variable return type) Deconstruct(); 
}
```

Comment: Short answer - you can't, since the return type is different.

Comment: Here is a *Lapalissade*: two different method signatures implies two differents methods... But you can perhaps use generics. Do you want generics ?

Comment: In terms of the generics answers below, I'd say, just because you **can**, does not mean you **should**. These should probably be different methods that do different things and have different names

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways of doing this but neither will be nice to use with the differing return types.

```
public interface IDeconstructable<T>
{
    T Deconstruct(); 
}
```

Then call it as `public class B : IDeconstructable<(Foo, Bar)>`

alternatively you could have

```
public interface IDeconstructable
{
    dynamic Deconstruct(); 
}
```

or

```
 public interface IDeconstructable
 {
     object Deconstruct(); 
 }
```

and make use of pattern matching to work out the Type of the returned value